# Chain .on() with .not() to remove unneeded elements from the object

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, onbeforeunload

I have a web form, that I bind the beforeunload event to the window to detect any changes to the form **except** the inputs that I do not need to include. So for example, an input that I don't need to bind the beforeunload event. It should only bind for inputs that will affect losing changes when navigating away from the window.

This is the current binding I have:

```
formChanged = false;
$('#main-form').on('change.form_change', 'input:not(.leave-change-allowed), textarea:not(.leave-change-allowed), select:not(.leave-change-allowed)', function()
{
    if(!formChanged)
    {
        formChanged = true;

        $(window).bind('beforeunload', function()
        {
            if(formChanged)
            {
                return 'Are you sure you want to navigate away from this window, you will lose unsaved changes.';
            }
        });
    }
    else
    {
        $(this).unbind('change.form_change');   
    }
});
```

As you can see I have included `:not(.leave-change-allowed)` to the elements in the selector, separated by commas to select the form elements. Although, I don't want to add the `not()` to the selector, because there may be few selectors I want to add to the `not()`, but I would need to apply to each form inputs `input`, `textarea` and `select`. Please bear in mind that these elements are dynamic, so I used `.on()` rather than `.change()`.

How can I chain the `.not()` function with the dynamic elements? So I keep the selector intact, and pass all the unnecessary elements in the `.not()` function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the target for the class inside the function :

```
formChanged = false;
$('#main-form').on('change.form_change', 'input, textarea, select', function(e) {
    if(! (formChanged || $(e.target).is('.leave-change-allowed')) ) {
        formChanged = true;
        $(window).on('beforeunload', function() {
            if(formChanged) {
                return 'Are you sure you want to navigate away from this window, you will lose unsaved changes.';
            }
        });
    } else {
        $(this).off('change.form_change');   
    }
});
```

Comment: That worked nicely, I have added a missing bracket in the `if` statement. Cheers.